# How to track changes between 3 files? Current file, another developer, my changes

Tags: git, themes, shopify, shopify-template

We use another dev a Shopify theme with liquid, js files. We make changes, theme devs make changes and every time need to update the theme is a pain because not sure where are my changes and where is theme developers updates. How to simply know it was removed by me? or added by me? or Theme update? There is a simple solution with git or another tool?

[image]

Comment: Like.... what `git blame` does?

Comment: Assuming you want to merge two branches, `git mergetool` will be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just like a plumber would not undertake to plumb your house without knowing how pipes and connectors work, one would not undertake a collaborative software project without mastering the tools of the trade as well, right? The tool most people use today, Git, is somewhat confusing, but one can go pretty far without too much trouble.

A tool like this manages all of the concerns you so carefully shared in your diagrams. It is more than enough for Shopify theme development between remote devs. You can even get GUI Git tools if you're unable to work the CLI. A handy guide for all is here: https://ohshitgit.com/

Master your tools, and the rest is easy.